# Getting user information from local storage - getUser

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to print the name of the logged in user in my application on the Navbar. I am using a getUser function to find the logged in user in local storage. Can someone explain me what's wrong / and guide me towards a solution? I tried googling but it wasn't very clear..

The console error I am getting is the following:

```
Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
        in p (at Navbar.js:30)
        in nav (at Navbar.js:28)
        in Navbar (at Default.js:8)
        in div (at Default.js:7)
        in Default (at Allchallenges.js:84)
```

---

```
//getUser
export const getUser = (user) => {
    console.log("user has been GET out of local storage (just before)")
    return JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("user"))
}

//setUser
export const setUser = (user) => {
    window.localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user))
    console.log("user has been SET out of local storage")
}


key:user

{friends: [], _id: "5ec5677db5b0fb73d48a3f23", username: "charlescodingtonight",…}
friends: []
password: "$2b$10$ZWLg4cK1YFiZbgxRlroKHu5l9Hicf1/wxMWhf0lFIdyXrGdyLNFDy"
username: "charlescodingtonight"
__v: 0
_id: "5ec5677db5b0fb73d48a3f23"
```

---

```
import React from "react"
import './Navbar.css';
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import {logout, getUser} from "../utils/auth"

class Navbar extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()

        this.state = {

        }
    }

    handleLogout(user){
        logout(user)
    }

    handleUser(user){
        const theLoggedUser = getUser(user)
        console.log(theLoggedUser)
        return theLoggedUser
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <nav className="navcontainer">
                <Link to="/allchallenges"><img className="logostreet" src="/images/logo.png" alt="logo" /></Link>
                <p className="welcomemessage">Welcome {this.handleUser}</p>
                <Link to="/allchallenges"><strong>All challenges</strong></Link>
                <Link to="/startchallenge"><strong>Start a challenge</strong></Link>
                <Link to="/profile"><strong>Profile settings</strong></Link>
                <Link to="/friends"><strong>Friends</strong></Link>
                <Link to="/about"><strong>About</strong></Link>
                <Link to="/" onClick={this.handleLogout}><strong>Log out</strong></Link>
            </nav>            
        )
    }
}

export default Navbar
```

Comment: can you post the code which is saving the user in localStorage or show how is user saved in localStorage?

Comment: I did an update!

Comment: what is `user`? a string or an object? Can you post the JSON that is saved in localStorage with `user` key?

Comment: thank you! have updated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getUser` function returns an object and it cannot be be rendered with jsx. You need to get username of the user instead of whole user object

Change `handleUser` function to return user's username

```
handleUser(user){
    const theLoggedUser = getUser(user)
    return theLoggedUser.username
}
```

you also need to call this function

```
<p className="welcomemessage">Welcome { this.handleUser() }</p>
```

Comment: great this works! I understand the JSX comment. Could you please explain why I need brackets after handleUser? I haven't used () after logout and that's working perfectly fine?

Comment: you don't call logout function yourself because it will be called automatically as a result of a click on logout button but you need to call `handleUser` function because it is not an event handler

Answer (score 0):

Here, you return string and function :`<p className="welcomemessage">Welcome {this.handleUser}</p>`.

I think u want this: `<p className="welcomemessage">Welcome {this.handleUser()}</p>`.

Comment: Thanks but still not working..there must be another issue I guess? Can you explain why my version was wront?